# Create folders/subfolders in an qt creator project

Tags: c++, qt, c++11, ide, qt-creator

In my Qt Project, I want to create some subfolders like *Audio* or *Video*.
Something like this:

```
Project\Media

Project\Media\Audio

Project\Media\Audio\Video
```

How I can do this?
Is there an way to add a new folder in Qt Creator? Or do I need to create this manually via the explorer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In qt you use [mkdir](http://doc.qt.digia.com/4.6/qdir.html#mkdir)

```
bool QDir::mkdir ( const QString & dirName ) const
```

which will create a subdirectory called (variable dirName)

You could also use [cmake](http://www.cmake.org/) which allows you to generate makefiles for every platform you need, itsteand of writing them manually. See code examples [here](http://techminded.net/blog/modular-c-projects-with-cmake.html)

Answer (score 2):

Currently the only way is to add or create file that is inside of the directory - then the directory will be also created in Projects view of the QtCreator. This is not really that bad, since you can create directory while adding a new class file to the project. When the file is added to the project, also all its parent directories will be reflected in the Projects view.